# Accessing exported gcode from Slic3r?

Tags: filesystem, directory, locate

I've been using Ubuntu for about a month and am definitely a novice, apologies if this question is trivial.

I use a program called Slic3r to create gcode (machine instructions) from stl files for 3D printing. Slic3r is supported in linux, but exports gcode to a directory called:

**home/artemis/.local/share/Repetierhost**

I can't seem to locate this directory in linux like I could in Windows. "Artemis" is my username.

If someone could give me a hand locating the exported gcode and perhaps making a link to the directory where new gcode is exported that would be excellent.

Am definitely enjoying the Ubuntu experience thus far too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Linux, all files starting with a dot are hidden files.

If you want to show hidden files in a terminal, use `ll` instead of `ls`

If you want to show hidden files in your file manager press "View" and then "Hidden files" (Or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>)

Alternatively, you can create a shortcut to the "Repetierhost" directory by right-clicking it, clicking "make link" and then moving the "Link To Repetierhost" to your desktop...

Comment: And as you're a reputation 1 user: don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, therefore "accepting" the answer, which is better then saying "thank you" as your and my reputation will go up...

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response and answer, I found the files I needed

Comment: De nada!  S'il vous plaît!  ("Lionel" is typically French, "Hernandez" is typically Spanish, so both)  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Files an folders that has names starting with "." are hidden. They are normally not displayed. To see them there is a command in menu.